# Manpage for Unix command: `command'

Tags: shell, unix

Where do I find a manpage for `command` command in Unix like shells?
It is listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Command_(Unix)&action=edit&redlink=1), but no man given.

Specifically, what does `-v` switch do in this command:
`command -v ls > /dev/null && export EDITOR='vim'`

Comment: In most of the command `-v` is for verbose (everything command is doing will be print to the terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) states:

> Runs command with arguments ignoring any shell function named command. Only shell builtin commands or commands found by searching the PATH are executed.
>
> If either the -V or -v option is supplied, a description of command is
>   printed. The -v option causes a single word indicating the command or
>   file name used to invoke command to be displayed; the -V option
>   produces a more verbose description. In this case, the return status
>   is zero if command is found, and non-zero if not.

Answer (score 0):

You get some info by typing `help command`. Since it is a builtin, you find it in `man bash`.